# Looping through columns then doing UCase

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that loops through columns to find a specific ending in a column (_END). If it finds that, then it will loop through the rows in that column, changing date formatting. This works as intended and I am having no issues with it. However, I need to UCase the rows as well. Right now, it would output a date like "01-Jan-2016". However, I need it to be "01-JAN-2016". I have code below that is giving me trouble.

```
    lngColHeaders = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For X = 1 To lngColHeaders
If (Right(Cells(5, X), 4)) = "_END" Then
    LastRowDates = Cells(Rows.Count, X).End(xlUp).Row
    For ZZ = 6 To LastRowDates Step 1
        Cells(ZZ, X).NumberFormat = "dd-MMM-YYYY"
        UCase (Cells(ZZ, X))
    Next ZZ
End If
Next X
```

Like I said, it seems to format them correctly, but `UCase (Cells(ZZ,X))` seems to do nothing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `Cells(ZZ, X) = UCase(Cells(ZZ, X))`

Comment: This does not output anything different.

Comment: Probably because the value is a date (underlying is just a number). Uppercasing a number doesn't change anything.

Comment: I believe this to be the issue as well BigBen. Is there any possible work around to this?

Comment: I think you'll need to format the cell as text to preserve the uppercase month name.

Comment: `Cells(ZZ, X) = UCase(Cells(ZZ, X).Text)` but be aware you lost date type then.

Comment: `Cells(ZZ, X) = UCase(Cells(ZZ, X).Text)` has no effect as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to format the cell as text, and then do your `UCase`, along with a `Format`.

```
Cells(ZZ, X).NumberFormat = "@"
Cells(ZZ, X).Value = UCase(Format(Cells(ZZ, X).Value, "dd-MMM-YYYY"))
```

Comment: You are a genius. This solves my issue. Thank you so much!!